# Exit event not called on all the tabs in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, events

I want to searialise and save the IsolatedStorageSettings.SiteSettings on all the tabs when the browser is closed. But I get the Exit event only on the tab that is presently active.

How is it possible that all the tab data is saved

```
public partial class App
    {
        private siteSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.SiteSettings;
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Exit += App_Exit;
        }

        private static void App_Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App app = (App)sender;
            app.Exit -= App_Exit;
            siteSettings.Save();
        }
}
```